# how to move position tabbar to up?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I need create custom tabbar with super class UITabBarController. But i don,t know how change position for tabbar items.

Now i determined this question with create subclass UIView and drow with zero component.![Now i have]
And this i can.t see tab bar, no more usefully storyboard tools. in runmode i have my toolbar.
but it no perfect :( effect. pls help? ferst day in cocoa  :)
![image in runmode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can goto 'File' -> 'New Project' and select 'Tabbed Application' as the template. This does all the ground work for you for a tabbed app! See this figure below:

[image]